# Submit Django search form and use .jquery .load for the results?

Tags: jquery, django

I'm building a search function with Jquery and Django. And Im wondering how I combine the jquery .load function with a form submit.

This is what im working with.

I click a link which open a dialog box, loads a child template with a Django form for search.

```
    <form method="post" id="searchform" action="/search/">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" id="submitsearch">Search</button><p>
    </form>
```

This function works great if i just redirect to a new page with the search results that i get back from my Django view when the form is handled.

But when the searchform is filled i want to submit and get the results back in the same dialog. I'm thinking something like this (but this is not working)...

```
    $("#dialog").on("click", "#submitsearch", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $("#dialog").load('search/' + $('#searchform').serialize());
```

Is it possible to use the ".load" into the dialog and submit the form at the same time? How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a data object as the second parameter to `$.load`, rather than adding it into the URL. When that second parameter is passed, jQuery does a POST. See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: Thanks for your first answer. Just a little follow up question. It's not possible to POST the form this way with load() if one of the field is a file (image) field right?